# Disable add to cart button based on WooCommerce product custom stock status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

Currently in woocommerce, add to cart button disabled, if the stock status is `out of stock`. I add new stock status with the label `Discontinued product` by using `woocommerce_product_stock_status_options`, now I am looking for a way to treat this product like it is out of stock.

Since I believe it is better to separate between a product that is not produced anymore and a product that produced and available in another store but it's not in stock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following to disable add to cart button based on a custom stock status *(where you will replace `custom_status_slug` by your custom status slug)*:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'filter_is_purchasable_callback', 10, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'filter_is_purchasable_callback', 10, 2 );
function filter_is_purchasable_callback( $purchasable, $product ) {
    if ( $product->get_stock_status() === 'custom_status_slug' ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $purchasable;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec, it solve my problem. Since I want to learn it better, would you please tell me about the number you mention in `add_filter`? Why you mention `10, 2`?

Comment: The last number (`2`) is the number of arguments (variables) that we use from the hooked function (mandatory when more than one) and `10` is the default hook priority (mandatory when you specify  the number of arguments).

Comment: Thanks for this! Works great with all the guides where you add your own stock status, strange that its not a part of those guides.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a solution that displays the stock status on the product page but not the 'add to cart' button

```html
add_filter('woocommerce_product_is_in_stock', 'filter_is_in_stock_callback', 10, 2 );
function filter_is_in_stock_callback( $stock, $product ) {
    if ( $product->get_stock_status() === 'custom_status_slug' ) {
        return false;       
    }
    return $stock;
}
```

Thanks for the first answer :)